# How to fix the error of video player program?

Tags: android, video

I read the Hello Android book. The app should play a video. I copied the video into res/raw. The App does not run. Why?

I get the following error:

```
video cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Video.java

```
package org.example.video;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Video extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
  video.setVideoPath("/raw/VID_20120604_142208.mp4");
  video.start();
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Exactly where do you get this error?  In Eclipse?

Comment: In eclipse. in VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video); line

Comment: I updated the answer try that

Comment: I try your update answer but R file of program was deleted and the program has 4 errors :( please help

Answer (score 1):

Use repair video tool to fix your video file, first download the trial version and check if all your files are displayed. If you are satisfied with the demo version then you can switch to full version to recover them. It is one of the finest software to [fix error of video file](http://www.repairvideo.net/repair-video-error-files.html) on Mac operating system. Hope this software helps you to sort out your problem. [From here](http://www.repairvideo.net/download/repairvideo.zip) you can download the software.

Answer (score 0):

Ran your code with a little modification  runs fine

```
  VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
  video.setVideoPath("android.resource://org.example.video/raw/learning");
  video.start();
```

Do not add the extension of file

Comment: Thanks for answer. I check this but it still gives the same old error.

Comment: Please help:( I did it but i dont know why R file was deleted and the program has 4 errors that all of these are "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: I did project/Clean and project/Build project but R file was not created. Why?

Comment: check your imports remove  org.example.video.R package if any and check you resource file also for errors.

Comment: I remove org.example.video package and i did project/Build Project again but R file was not created.

Comment: I create new project and i tried to re-create the program. Th program is run but does not to play video. my phone and emulator shows a black screen. why?

Comment: try with  some other video file and keep simpler name :)

Comment: I rename video file to temp name and i try again but my mobile phone displays a black screen :(( ---> video.setVideoPath("/raw/temp.mp4");